# Exception when multipart form POST interrupted by session timeout results in an

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, session-timeout, multipartform-data

We have Spring security with CAS (I don't think CAS is the problem).

The **problem is NOT the session timeout**, rather how this timeout is handled.

1. request a form: GET /someform
2. fill out a multipart form
3. restart the server, or delete JSESSIONID
4. submit the form: POST /someform (with multipart data)
5. user is redirected to the login screen
6. after login user is redirected to the form: GET /someform
7. spring tries to re-post the saved form (I think it's using DefaultSavedRequest)
8. it tries to call the controller function mapped to: POST /someform, but the request is not multipart
9. we get an exception:

> Failed to invoke handler method
>   [public
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView
>   com.xxx.xxx.XXXController.xxxPost(org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartHttpServletRequest)];
>   nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   Current request is not of type
>   org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartHttpServletRequest:
>   com.secondmarket.web.UrlLowerCaseFilter$LowerCaseUrlServletRequestWrapper@77fb58b6

This is the code that saves the request to the session upon AccessDeniedException, it's in HttpSessionRequestCache (called by ExceptionTranslationFilter):

```
public void saveRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    if (!justUseSavedRequestOnGet || "GET".equals(request.getMethod())) {
        DefaultSavedRequest savedRequest = new DefaultSavedRequest(request, portResolver);

        if (createSessionAllowed || request.getSession(false) != null) {
            // Store the HTTP request itself. Used by AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter
            // for redirection after successful authentication (SEC-29)
            request.getSession().setAttribute(WebAttributes.SAVED_REQUEST, savedRequest);
            logger.debug("DefaultSavedRequest added to Session: " + savedRequest);
        }
    }

}
```

How can i owverwrite HttpSessionRequestCache or ExceptionTranslationFilter to NOT save the request if it's a multipart request?

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem by modifying controller method signature.

Previously, MultipartHttpServletRequest was in the method signature.  When spring came back from login round trip, it tried calling this method with regular HttpServletRequest, and failed.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/xxx", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView doAmlCheckPost(MultipartHttpServletRequest req) {
    UserInfo currentUserInfo = UserInfo.getCurrentUserInfo(req);

    MultipartFile someFile = req.getFile("someFile");
```

The fix is to use regular RequestMapping, and pick up the files from the URL.  If request is not instanceof MultipartHttpServletRequest - redirect to the GET method, which redisplays the form

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/xxx", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView doAmlCheckMultipartPost(HttpServletRequest req, @RequestParam(value = "someFile", required = false) MultipartFile someFile) {

    if(!(req instanceof MultipartHttpServletRequest)){
        return "redirect:/xxx";
    }
```

So the flow is now as follows:

1. request a form: GET /someform
2. fill out a multipart form
3. restart the server, or delete JSESSIONID
4. submit the form: POST /someform (with multipart data) WHAT HAPPENS HERE IS REQUEST IS SAVED IN THE SESSION, BUT THERE IS NO WAY TO SAVE MULTIPART DATA, IT'S BINARY AND CANNOT BE SERIALIZED
5. user is redirected to the login screen
6. after login user is redirected to the form: GET /someform
7. spring tries to re-post the saved form (I think it's using DefaultSavedRequest) SPRING NOW CALLS THE POST METHOD WITH HttpServletRequest, not MultipartHttpServletRequest.  We detect that it's not MultipartHttpServletRequest and redirect to the GET page, redisplaying the form to the user